# Bayesian conjugate updating when the likelihood can be approximated by a finite mixture of normals?

Tags: bayesian, mixture-distribution, conjugate-prior

I'm facing a situation where I'd like to do Bayesian conjugate updating, but both the prior and the likelihood (a Student-t) can only be approximated by a finite mixture of normals. I know that a normal likelihood + mixture prior is a straightforward case (see e.g. old Persi Diaconis and Donald Ylvisaker paper) or the [RBesT R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RBesT/vignettes/introduction_normal.html). But what if the likelihood is also described by a mixture of normal? Can you do conjugate updating for each component? How do the mixture weights change a-posteriori in that case?

Comment: It's a $O(k^n)$ complexity conjugate...

Comment: Here's a related question on [using Gaussian mixtures as priors of Gaussian likelihoods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/360487).

Comment: Addendum: it appears that for conjugate updating with Gaussian mixture priors you will also need a likelihood that is a Gaussian mixture. In that case, the posterior is also a Gaussian mixture with updated parameters. For more details, have a look at part III of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.11753).